# Racket: render a video to a canvas

Tags: racket

I am trying to display a video within a panel using `racket/gui`. It looks like the library to use is video. The `video-player%` class extends `frame%` which will not be contained inside a panel so I assume I have to use a video-player-server%. Is that correct?

It looks like the `video-player-server%` has a `set-canvas` method which seems like what I want, however if I provide it a canvas I get an error saying `get-video-width` is not defined on canvas. Is there a subclass of `canvas` I am missing?

This is what I have come up with so far.

```
#lang racket/gui                                   

(require video/base video/player)                  

(define video (clip "toystory.mp4"))               

(define video-server (new video-player-server%     
                       (video video)))          

(define (make-video parent)                        
  (define panel (new panel%                        
                   (parent parent)))            

  (define canvas (new canvas%                      
                   (min-width 300)              
                   (parent panel)))         

  ; The problem appears to be with this line                                              
  (send video-server set-canvas canvas)            

  (displayln (send video-server get-fps))          

  panel)                                           

(provide make-video)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a `video-canvas%` exposed by the video library 
[described here.](https://github.com/videolang/video/blob/stable/video/private/video-canvas.rkt)